# Rails 5 How to get a count of all the rows in each table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I had a old script that worked for me on rails 4

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.map { |t| "#{t} => " + ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select count(*) from #{t}").first['count'] }
```

but this is not returning anything on a rails 5 project :(

Answer (score 17):

This should work:

```
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.map { |t| {t=>  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select count(*) from #{t}")[0]} }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.inject({}) { |h,t| h[t] =  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select count(*) from #{t}")[0].values.first; h }
```

will produce nice output like:

```
{
  "users" => 12,
  "teams" => 5
}
```